# Cannot rename previously created folder

Tags: vb.net, permissions, rename

I have following code that takes a local directory and copies it with a temporary name on a network drive.

Once there, it Waits a moment, deletes the original folder, and then renames the previously uploaded folder to the proper name.

All steps work fine, except for the last one. When it tries to rename the folder it throws an error saying that I do not have the permissions needed. Why? The folder is created by the program, it can delete the other folder just fine, why wouldnt it have the rights to rename it? Is it somehow "busy" or "used"? Any idea on how to fix this problem?

It happensonly from time to time, not every time.

```
        copy("c:\somefolder\", "Y:\someotherfolder\temporary folder\")
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
        Directory.Delete("Y:\someotherfolder\original name\" , True)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Directory.Move("Y:\someotherfolder\temporary folder\", "Y:\someotherfolder\original name\") ''this line causes trouble
```

thank you!

Comment: The program might still have an open connection, which would be causing the move to fail. Also make sure that you don't have any read only attributes set in the source directory.

Comment: Have you tested this program using different times in `Thread.Sleep()`? Try using a longer wait time. Maybe the previous step isn't complete yet. `Thread.Sleep(1000)` is only a one second wait time.